# react virtual list updatable item count

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Libraries like `react-virtualized`, `react-window` and `react-virtuoso` have `item count` property like in code below from `materal-ui`. However it is located within `return`. Is there any way to make `item counter`updatable?

```
export default function VirtualizedList() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FixedSizeList height={400} width={300} itemSize={46} itemCount={200}>
        {renderRow}
      </FixedSizeList>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "way to make item counter updatable"? Plz, explain more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can pass on a dynamic value to the itemCount property in FixedSizeList. It take care of it and also ensure that the scroll remain where it is currently

A sample code would look like

```
const Example = () => {
  const [rowCount, setRowCount] = useState(10);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("changed");
      setRowCount(1000);
    }, 10000);
  }, []);
  console.log(rowCount);
  return (
    <List
      className="List"
      height={150}
      itemCount={rowCount}
      itemSize={35}
      width={300}
    >
      {Row}
    </List>
  );
};
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-hill-oh8d8?file=/index.js:307-692)

Comment: Wow! That demo is impressive! However using a hook subbed to changes of initial value on that had failed. I've added following `let cur = useRef(2) `, `const [rowCount, setRowCount] = useState(cur.current);` and   `useEffect(() => {
    console.log("update", cur.current);
    setTimeout(() => {
      cur.current =  4
      console.log("update" , cur.current);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);`

 `useEffect(() => {
    console.log("changed",cur.current);
    setRowCount(cur.current);
  }, [cur]);`

Comment: The problem here is that log shows `update 2` `changed 2 ` `update 4`. Second change is not called yet update was performed. Also there's a warning `Warning: unmountComponentAtNode(): The node you're attempting to unmount was rendered by React and is not a top-level container. Instead, have the parent component update its state and rerender in order to remove this component.`

Comment: You really should not pass a ref to the dependency of useEffect and I am not sure why you are mixing state with ref in this case

Comment: I've used `useRef` simply because `eslint` warns. Anyway, even without it hook did not trigger second time after updating `cur` value.

Comment: can you share a demo of what you are trying to do

Comment: sure I'd love to but I cant find `share` button in codesandbox.edit: https://pastebin.com/EvCarnG3

Comment: The issue is you are defining cur within functional component as a variable and everytime your component -rerenders that gets re-initialized. Also its not a variable that will trigger re-render so that the useEffect can make a comparison. I really don't understand why are you trying to make the useEffect depend on a local  variable. either it should come from props or be its own state

Comment: here is my actual attempt to make an app https://pastebin.com/MsJXs2nw  where commented `FixedSizeList` is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214328/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-jayjayabrams).